# Is there a function in SAS that can convert a day of the year to a date?

Tags: date, datetime, input, sas, put

Suppose that I have a data set which contains a variable with days 1-365, representing each day of the year 2020. Is there a function that exists that can convert this day value to a date value mm/dd/2020 ? I know how to do this with "hard coding" and using conditional logic/basic arithmetic or writing my own format, but I wanted to see if there was a more concise way to deal with this.

Conversely, is there a pre-existing function that can convert a date to its appropriate day of the year value? Ie id I had data that was structured like 01/02/2020, I want it represented by the integer value "2".

Comment: Not aware of a function but basic math works well. `date_want = mdy(1, 1, 2020) + days - 1;`

Comment: Here's a list of the date and time functions available. Navigating by category lets you see all the functions available. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n01f5qrjoh9h4hn1olbdpb5pr2td.htm#p1nv3mo1r8yzmyn1ni5wis9to651

Comment: I already had the solution for basic arithmetic (as mentioned in the OP), but I ended up finding the function I was looking for for my purposes (intnx()) for the first part of the question. Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no need to use INTNX() to increment a date, time or datetime value when you are incrementing in the base unit used to enumerate the values.  So days for date values or seconds for time or datetime values. you can use use addition or subtraction.

Comment: Hi: yes, I understand that. But as mentioned in the question, there was a restriction on using basic arithmetic as a method.

Answer (score 2):

Closest thing would be the [DATEJUL()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p15eh3xh4qqs3in17ivbz5ywneff.htm) function.

```
date = datejul( year * 1000 + day_of_year);
```

But it might be clearer to use the more normal MDY() function.

```
date = mdy(1,1,year) - 1 + day_of_year ;
```

To reverse it you can could use something like:

```
day_of_year = date - intnx('year',date,0) + 1;
```

Comment: Or intnx? date = intnx('day', '01Jan2020'd, day_of_year) - 1;

Comment: Why use INTNX() to move by days?

Comment: Only because it's the question asked by the OP.

Comment: @reeza had the correct answer for my purposes but I think this solution (using the first function) is also really cute! Didn't know about datejul()